# How to stop IE opening Excel spreadsheets in embedded mode?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, internet-explorer

When we open an Excel workbook with Internet Explorer (`D:\Book1.xlsx` in address bar) - IE opens the Excel workbook in embedded mode. It triggers Excel with the following option `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE -Embedding`.

Is there any way I can stop Internet Explorer from opening Excel in Embedded mode and to trigger it in a normal mode?

Comment: @Jawa Any update on this is greatly appreciateed